# Need Simple java agent and Transformer classes for re-defining method signature at runtime

Tags: java

I need to use a java agent and Transformer classes to modify already loaded class definition at runtiime.
I have followed http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/ steps. But still not getting complete flow.

Comment: which part of the tutorial gives you such an error? you need to be more clear about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Instrumentation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses-java.lang.Class...-) states that

> The *retransformation* **must not** add, remove or rename fields or methods,
>   **change the signatures of methods**, or change inheritance.

You may not change signatures of already-loaded classes, only before they are loaded for the first time. Please do provide more information on what went wrong (e.g. exception stack). Maybe we can help.

Comment: I am getting below error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mypack.MyUser: method <i nit>()V not found at mypack.MyMainClass.main(MyMainClass.java:18)

Comment: package mypack;

public class MyMainClass
{
    static
    {
        MyJavaAgent.initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("MyMainClass.main()1");
        MyUser user = new MyUser();
        user.getName();
    }

}

Comment: public class MyUser 
{

       public String getName() 
    {
        System.out.println("######### MyUser.getName()");
        return "foo";
 
    }
}

Comment: Plz explain me when we will get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mypack.MyUser: method <i nit>()V not found at mypack.MyMainClass.main(MyMainClass.java:18)

Comment: @user1849088, Please provide full exception stack for more details. 

Generally, "<init>" is the constructor's method name. you are calling something like "new MyUser()", but class does not have a parameter-less constructor. Class probably has a different constructor that expects parameters (and thus, a default constructor was not created for it by the compiler). Could be the transformer destroyed it somehow, *before* class was loaded (cannot alter method signature after class was already loaded). Either create a default constructor for it (e.g. "MyUser(){}") or call an existing constructor.